# Format number input dynamicly in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, pipe

I have this input field:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="currentValue" (keyup)="onInput($event)" (change)="onFieldLeave(currentValue)"/>
```

and I would like to format the numbers in this style: '15 354.58'

I have also implemented the following function on keyup:

```
public allowedChars: string[] = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '.'];    
onInput(event: any) {
        if(event.key === ',') {
          this.currentValue = this.currentValue.toString().replace(',', '.');
        } else if (!this.allowedChars.includes(event.key)) {
          this.currentValue = this.currentValue.toString().replace(event.key, '');
        } else {
          this.currentValue = this.decimalPipe.transform(this.currentValue, '1.0-2', 'fr-FR').replace(',', '.');
        }
      }
```

but the input gets formatted like that: '1 5354.58'.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular offers a special mechanism called directives - they allow you to create custom components that allow you to manipulate DOM elements, control the display of elements, enable and disable elements, and create custom attributes. A directive can be used in different contexts, such as templates, components, or attributes. Their use allows for better organization of the code, increasing its readability, facilitating testing and ensuring greater flexibility in application development. It will also work in your case, and by the way, I will add that this example is also called "mask" - I mean directives that visually modify the format of values in controls.
I recommend reading about directives and trying to create your own custom directives to get the hang of it.

Angular docs:
https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#declaring-directives

Below I leave an example of a directive that should meet your expectations:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appNumberFormat]'
})
export class NumberFormatDirective {
  private decimalPipe = new DecimalPipe('en-US');

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private control: NgControl) {}

  @HostListener('focus')
  onFocus() {
    const currentValue = this.el.nativeElement.value;
    this.el.nativeElement.value = this.cleanValue(currentValue);
  }

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.key === ',' || event.key === '.') {
      event.preventDefault();
      const currentValue = this.el.nativeElement.value;
      if (!currentValue.includes('.')) {
        this.el.nativeElement.value += '.';
      }
      return;
    }
  }

  @HostListener('input', ['$event'])
  onInput() {
    const currentValue = this.cleanValue(this.el.nativeElement.value);
    const formattedValue = this.formatValue(currentValue, '1.0-2');
    this.control.control.setValue(currentValue);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.el.nativeElement.value = formattedValue;
    }, 0);
  }

  @HostListener('blur')
  onBlur() {
    const currentValue = this.el.nativeElement.value;
    const formattedValue = this.formatValue(this.cleanValue(currentValue), '1.0-2');
    this.el.nativeElement.value = formattedValue;
    this.control.control.setValue(this.cleanValue(formattedValue));
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.el.nativeElement.value = formattedValue;
    }, 0);
  }

  private formatValue(value: string, format: string): string {
    const numberValue = parseFloat(value);
    if (isNaN(numberValue)) {
      return '';
    }
    return this.decimalPipe.transform(numberValue, format).replace(/,/g, ' ');
  }

  private cleanValue(value: string): string {
    return value.replace(/\s+/g, '');
  }
}
```

Remember to add the directive to the declaration in the application module. If you have more modules, and the directive is, for example, in the "SharedModule" module, then in addition to the declaration, remember to export the directive, if you actually export such a module to other modules.

Example of declaration only (declaration is mandatory) and optional export:

```
const DIRECTIVES = [
  NumberFormatDirective
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...COMPONENTS, ...DIRECTIVES],
  imports: [...MODULES],
  exports: [...MODULES, ...COMPONENTS, ...DIRECTIVES]
})
export class SharedModule {
}
```

And the example of using directive in your input control:

```
<input type="text" appNumberFormat [(ngModel)]="currentValue" />
```

However, if you prefer to use your own function, which is not a directive, you can improve the code as follows:

```
onInput(event: any) {
    if (event.key === ',' || event.key === '.') {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (!this.currentValue.includes('.')) {
        this.currentValue += '.';
      }
    } else if (!this.allowedChars.includes(event.key)) {
      this.currentValue = this.currentValue.toString().replace(event.key, '');
    } else {
      const cleanValue = this.currentValue.replace(/\s+/g, '');
      const formattedValue = this.decimalPipe.transform(cleanValue, '1.0-2').replace(/,/g, ' ');
      this.currentValue = formattedValue;
    }
  }
```

The main difference between this code and the directive is that the blur event is not handled. The directive has a built-in blur event that keeps the formatting even when you click outside the control.

Your original code had the following problems:

Instead of blocking the comma entry and converting it to a period, you were entering a comma and then trying to convert it to a period after the input. This caused the comma to be visible for a very short time before it was converted to a period.

Formatting a number with decimalPipe did not fully match expected formatting. In the original code you used 'fr-FR' formatting, but in the directive we use 'en-US' formatting which is more appropriate for this case.

Using decimalPipe.transform() in the context of this code causes number formatting issues when entering a value, because this function converts the value to its formatted form but does not allow further editing of the value. In the modified code, we use the formatting of the values only after entering the correct characters, which allows the values to continue to be entered in the expected format.